# PhpStorm Scss Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - compile

Tags: css, ruby, sass

Can't convert my scss files to css in my editor (PHPSTORM) but I can convert my css to css.min is that about the editor or something else?

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/scss.bat compile path/to/project style.scss
```

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - compile   Use
>   --trace for backtrace.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1